# Bison: Get the token on error

Tags: bison

I have an error but i am very confused what the parser thinks the token is. I see an array of name at yytname and a function called yytokenName but they are static.

In my error rule how do i print out or pass the name of the error token?

Answer (score 1):

I you use the glr option yyerror have a YYLTYPE parameter which contain the token(s) location provided by the lexical analyser.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Error-Reporting